# Multiple views inside TableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

[This is how my cell looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0DtU.png)

[This is the structuring of my cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FopUZ.png)

**I have a JSON format looks like this:**

```
{
"status": true,
"session": true,
"make": "Ford",
"year": "2015",
"model": "EXPLORER",
"trim": "Base",
"engine": "3.5L V6 - Gas",
"make_id": "96",
"year_id": "100",
"model_id": "284",
"trim_id": "358",
"engine_id": "510",
"title": "Ford 2015 EXPLORER Base 3.5L V6 - Gas - Alternator",
"group_image": "http://www.orouad.com/test_aspns/image/catalog/Ford/67dc394bb5c7839fe09bcbae85210b90.svg",
"parts": [
    {
        "product_id": "7760",
        "group_id": "317991",
        "part_number": "DG1Z-10346-B",
        "part_name": "Alternator",
        "part_image": "http://www.orouad.com/test_aspns/image/cache/placeholder-130x130.png",
        "description": "",
        "part_index": "1",
        "quantity": "0",
        "price": "SAR  0.00",
        "after_market": [],
        "superseded": [
            {
                "part_id": "11695",
                "part_no": "AA5Z*10346*B",
                "manufacturer": null,
                "description": "Alternator",
                "price": "SAR  0.00",
                "quantity": "0"
            },
            {
                "part_id": "12187",
                "part_no": "GL*980*",
                "manufacturer": null,
                "description": "Alternator",
                "price": "SAR  0.00",
                "quantity": "0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "product_id": "7761",
        "group_id": "318048",
        "part_number": "DG1Z-10346-F",
        "part_name": "Alternator",
        "part_image": "http://www.orouad.com/test_aspns/image/cache/placeholder-130x130.png",
        "description": "",
        "part_index": "1",
        "quantity": "0",
        "price": "SAR  0.00",
        "after_market": [],
        "superseded": [
            {
                "part_id": "11581",
                "part_no": "8A4Z*10346*A",
                "manufacturer": null,
                "description": "Alternator",
                "price": "SAR  0.00",
                "quantity": "0"
            },
            {
                "part_id": "12032",
                "part_no": "DG1Z*10346*A",
                "manufacturer": null,
                "description": "Alternator",
                "price": "SAR  0.00",
                "quantity": "0"
            },
            {
                "part_id": "12186",
                "part_no": "GL",
                "manufacturer": null,
                "description": "Alternator",
                "price": "SAR  7.00",
                "quantity": "0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "product_id": "7762",
        "group_id": "318101",
        "part_number": "GB5Z-10346-C",
        "part_name": "Alternator",
        "part_image": "http://www.orouad.com/test_aspns/image/cache/placeholder-130x130.png",
        "description": "",
        "part_index": "1",
        "quantity": "0",
        "price": "SAR  0.00",
        "after_market": [],
        "superseded": [
            {
                "part_id": "11848",
                "part_no": "BL3Z-10346-A",
                "manufacturer": null,
                "description": "Alternator",
                "price": "SAR  0.00",
                "quantity": "0"
            },
            {
                "part_id": "12079",
                "part_no": "DG1Z-10346-C",
                "manufacturer": null,
                "description": "Alternator",
                "price": "SAR  0.00",
                "quantity": "0"
            },
            {
                "part_id": "12186",
                "part_no": "GL",
                "manufacturer": null,
                "description": "Alternator",
                "price": "SAR  7.00",
                "quantity": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want to show all "parts" as well as "aftermarket" and "superseded" parts if there is any value inside array "aftermarket" and "superseded" otherwise hide the aftermarket and superseded view and just show the parts view.

My problem is how do I show multiple views of aftermarket and superseded if there is multiple value inside these array.

**This is the code to show if there is only one value in aftermarket or superseded**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return partsData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "partsDetailCell") as!  VehiclePartsDetailCell
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    let partData = partsData[indexPath.row]
    if (partData.afterMarket?.isEmpty)!{
        cell.bottomView.isHidden = true
    }else{
        cell.bottomView.isHidden = false
        cell.bottomPartLbl.text = partData.afterMarket![0].partNo
        cell.bottomDesLbl.text =  partData.afterMarket![0].description
        cell.bottomPriceLbl.text = partData.afterMarket![0].price
    }
    cell.serialNoLbl.text = partData.partIndex
    cell.partNoLbl.text = partData.partNumber
    cell.descriptionLbl.text = partData.partName
    cell.priceLbl.text = partData.price
    cell.cartBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "cart.png"), for: .normal)
    return cell
}
```

I anyone provide any suggestion on how to populate data or to use multiple cells inside tableview.

Comment: Mention number of sections you required and cellForRowAt indexPath: create multiple cells in each section. if indexPath.section = 0 { //First model cells } else if indexPath.section = 1 { //Display second model cells } else {//Display third model cells}

Comment: I don't want to create separate sections I just want to show the aftermarket and superseded part just below the part it is related to if there is any value or just hide them.And the other parts also like so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pseudo code just for example, you have to modify it.
First you have to set cell size  with this method

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return currentCellSize + partsData[indexPath.row].superseded.count * supersededSize + afmNormalHight * partsData[indexPath.row].afterMarket.count
}
```

After taht you need to change your cell creation to be like this

```
var currentCount = 0
 for afterMarket in partData.afterMarke {
     let afm = AfterMarketView()
     afm.bottomPartLbl.text = partData.afterMarket![0].partNo
     afm.bottomDesLbl.text =  partData.afterMarket![0].description
     afm.bottomPriceLbl.text = partData.afterMarket![0].price
     afm.frmae = CGFrame(0, normalCellSize + afmNormalHight * currentCount, cell.frame.size.width, afmNormalHight)
    currentCount++
   cell.addSubview(afm)
  }
```

Comment: Thank I will give it a try!

Comment: I hope you understand the idea. Please, let me know if it is okay or if there is some problem.

Comment: what is the use of currentCount?

Comment: to calculate where in the cell is current afterMarket. For example cell without afterMarkets will be 50px. Position of first after market on y axis will be 50, on second one should be 50 +  hight of AfterMarketView, on third one is 50 + 2 * hight  of AfterMarketView.

Comment: How do I change the text of label inside after view.Currently I attached the labels to the cell(as you can see on code above).

Comment: you should create custom UIView wich will  be something like:
class AfterMarketView: UIView {
 var bottomPartLbl: UILabelel ....} and also if there is some specific arrangment of all labels you can initiate this view from xib file